Aviso de brecha de seguridad en login con chrome - Codeigniter 4 Azure WebApp
no se si alguien podria indicarme la razon de la notificacion y como solucionarlo,
Chrome me muestra una notificacion una brecha de seguridad tras loguearme en un proyecto de Codeigniter 4, alojado en Azure en una WebApp corriendo sobre linux y php 8.2, conectado a una BD de mysql tambien alojada en Azure.
La notificacion unicamente me la muestra sobre Chrome, en firefox y brave no la muestra, en local tampoco.

notificacion de chrome:
Cambia la contraseña.
La contraseña que acabas de usar se ha encontrado en una brecha de seguridad de datos. El Gestor de contraseñas de Google te recomienda que cambies tu contraseña ahora.
en mi .env ya configure lo que supuse que podria generar dicha notificacion:
CI_ENVIRONMENT = production
app.baseURL = 'XXXX'
app.forceGlobalSecureRequests = true

tambien añadi el certificado ssl para la conexion a mysql añadiendo el archivo .pem al proyecto, y en la configuracion del servidor de mysql en Azure modifique el parametro de servidor "require_secure_transport" a TRUE
mi formulario en la vista de login es el siguiente:
        <form action="<?= base_url('/login'); ?>" method="post">
            <?= csrf_field() ?>
            <div class="mb-3 text-start">
                <label for="InputEmail" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
                <input type="username" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="username" value="<?= session()->getFlashdata('old_email') ?? '' ?>">
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3 text-start">
                <label for="InputPassword" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="InputPassword" name="password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Acceder</button>
        </form>

gracias de antemano, es mi primera pregunta en stackoverflow espero haberla realizado donde corresponde, tengo experiencia en Laravel, en Codeigniter me inicie hace relativamente poco.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Bienvenido.. no entendiste el mensaje.. no tiene nada que ver ni con tu codigo ni con nada.. te esta diciendo que ese Pass se filtro en una filtracion masiva de datos, y que lo cambies... nada que ver, con nada de otras cosas...

Revista esta pregunta, tal vez responda a lo que estás buscando ¿Por qué Google Chrome regresa la alerta de "Tu contraseña quedo expuesta debido a una violacion de la seguridad de los datos"?
